# How to use server side observers in a multi server environment?

Tags: nginx, meteor

I've recently added another server to my app and placed an Nginx load balancer in front of them. So a load balancer, and two servers running the same app. This is all very new to me, and I'm running into issues I wouldn't have in a single server environment. One of them is that the server side observers on the app run on BOTH servers, which is undesirable. For example, I'll have the following observer.

```
                var initializing = true;
                Jobs.find({
                    $or: [{
                        processed: {
                            $ne: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        restart: true
                    }]
                }).observeChanges({
                    added: function(id, doc) {
                        if (!initializing) {
                            // do stuff
                        }
                    }
                });
                initializing = false;
```

Which then runs on both servers. I only want it to run on one - I don't care which one, but I guess the one that the user is currently on makes sense. What are some of my options? I wouldn't think this is an uncommon scenario but I wasn't able to find anything online. My current workaround is to remove the observers off the servers, and have a THIRD server that does all of the observing. However, this won't scale if my app takes off, which obviously I hope it does. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you set an environment variable on one of the servers and have the server code check for it?

Comment: could you explain your comment a little more @sbking? I'm not sure where you're going with it. how would that help?

Answer (score 2):

I'll present two possible solutions to this problem: designated master, and dynamic master.

### Designated Master

In this strategy, we'll elect a single server to act as the "master" for the job task. There are a variety of ways you can do this, but as @sbking suggested above, using an environment variable is probably the easiest. On one of you servers, set a variable like `MASTER_SERVER=1`. On all servers you can check for the existence of said variable, and run the task only if it's set. For example:

**server A start script**

```
export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL=https://app.example.com
export MASTER_SERVER=1
forever start /path/to/your/bundle/main.js
```

**server B start script**

```
export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL=https://app.example.com
forever start /path/to/your/bundle/main.js
```

**server/main.js**

```js
if (process.env.MASTER_SERVER) {
  Jobs.find(...).observeChanges(...);
}
```

Because only A was started with `MASTER_SERVER` set, it will be the only server to perform the task. While this strategy is simple to implement, it has one critical flaw - it isn't fault tolerant. If A were to fail, the task would not continue to run.

### Dynamic Master

Rather than pre-designating a master, an alternative approach is for each server to attempt to become the master at regular intervals. This strategy works well if you can convert you task into something that looks like a cron job. Then you need only use [synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) which will ensure that only one server can execute the task during that interval. In this example, each server will attempt to run the task every minute:

**server/main.js**

```js
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Process all the things!',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    return parser.text('every 1 mins');
  },
  job: function() {
    // do job processing here
    return true;
  }
});

SyncedCron.start();
```

This is a more robust solution, however you would need to decide if checking the `Jobs` collection at regular intervals (rather than observing its changes) fits your use case.

Comment: Just to confirm, the dynamic method would require you to timestamp updates and store the highest timestamp in each batch of data processed by the cron job?

Comment: thanks David, this has given me some ideas to test out.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using nginx. Nginx can do server affinity on the upstream module. This will make sure that each client will hit the same server. The are many disadvantages to server affinity but meteor lends it self to using server affinity.

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;

    sticky cookie srv_id expires=1h domain=.example.com path=/;
}
```

There are other methods with nginx. above is the `cookie` method, but could use `route` or `learn`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html